# Volver a commit anterior en la misma rama tanto local como en github

Tags: git, github, git-commit

Mi duda es la siguiente, tengo los siguientes commit:

```
4e3cb77 cambio local
7978945 despues de revertir el cambio de hensel
60e65f9 actualizacion
8397e64 Update prueba.txt
c9bd0fb primer cambio online
39c7cc0 Base de la prueba, archivo inicial local prueba
```

¿Cual es el proceso a seguir para volver a un commit en particular(el que yo quiera) tanto de forma local como en github.com quedandome en la misma rama? Hasta ahora solo lo puedo hacer de la siguiente forma:

Una vez veo los log hago un `git checkout` + el comit al que quiero ir y me sale este mensaje:

> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make
>   experimental changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits
>   you make in this state without impacting any branches by performing
>   another checkout. If you want to create a new branch to retain commits
>   you create, you may do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout
>   command again. Example:   git checkout -b
>
> HEAD is now at 39c7cc0... Base de la prueba, archivo inicial local prueba

Es ahi donde me veo obligado a crear una nueva rama con:

```
git checkout -b rama
git push --set-upstream origin rama
```

Sin embargo de esta forma no obstante de crear una rama adicional tambien se pierden los commits que estaban despues de volver a ese commit osea que si tengo 10 commits y volvi al commit 7 los commit 8/9/10 no se ven el log de la nueva rama y no quiero eso. No se si fui lo suficientemente claro cualquier duda favor indicarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma correcta de hacerlo es usando el comando [`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert), pues mantiene un histórico de lo que pasó en esa rama (a modo de bitácora).

De esta forma, el comando `git revert 4e3cb77` modificará tu copia local revirtiendo los cambios que hiciste en el commit `4e3cb77 "cambio local"`. Si querés restaurar la rama a un punto específico, podés reversar múltiples commits hasta llegar al punto deseado.

Comment: me dijeron que usara git reset --hard + el commit y luego git push -f origin master y me funciono a medias, ya que volvio a la version que yo queria pero elimino el registro de todos los commits posterior al commit al que yo deseaba volver y eso me perjudica. Ahora bien con git revert se mantiene el historico pero y si quiero volver 25 commits atras tardaria mucho, no hay un comando que me envie retorne al commit deseado y mantenga el historico sin tener que tardar tanto

Comment: Lamentablemente, no hay una forma de hacer todas esas reversiones de forma automática. La otra alternativa es crear una rama a partir de ese commit, usar esa como tu rama principal y dejar la anterior como huérfana.